# Reading out informations about an device via SNMP

Tags: php, snmp

I want to program an application with PHP which can read out the information from an device such as the running OS on it or which software is installed. I looked in the PHP manual but it's not very helpful.

Comment: I don't know SNMP but does `phpinfo()` work?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski phpinfo() only says that SNMP is enabled.